# Mat vs array for pixel-pixel manipulation in OpenCv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, mat

I am creating a method within a class to take a Mat and perform some pixel-pixel manipulation on it.
Would it be more speed and memory efficient to use Mat with .at  , Mat with row pointer or basic array manipulation??

Answer (score 1):

Basic array manipulations generally faster, but it will depend on your implementation.

Accessing Mat with .at method involves different additional checks (like index range check).

Comment: That's true only in debug. No checks in release

Comment: Useful recomendations here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html